# Schengen visa duration of stay

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

Italian consulate gave me the following details:

- Valid for: STATI SCHENGEN
- From: Oct 11-30, 2015
- Type of Visa: C
- Number of Entries: 1
- Duration of Stay: 5 days

My concern is, I will be attending a training in Verona, Italy from Oct 11-15, 2015. My connecting flight from Saudi Arabia is Paris, France. After my visit to Verona, can I still go to Paris and stay there for two more days before I go back to Saudi Arabia regardless if the duration stay approved was only 5 days?

Answer (score 4):

Your visa is valid for a 5-day period within the time window encompassing 00:00:00 of the 11th of October and 23:59:59 of the 30th of October. If you stay longer than your allowed number of days - 5 - you'll effectively be overstaying and might be subject to a fine, or even banned from entering the Schengen area in the future.

Note: 5 days does not mean 120 hours: You must leave by 23:59:59 on the fifth day.

Comment: So it means i cannot stay in france after the approves duartion stay? Eventhough it is still in the schengen region?

Comment: @AlexPunzalan Exactly. You can stay in the Schengen area for exactly 5 days.

Comment: @AlexPunzalan It's because France is in the Schengen area that you can enter it at all. But you still have to abide by the maximum stay you were granted. If you needed more, you should have mentioned your plan to stay in Paris on your visa application. The limitations (date of validity, number of entries, maximum stay) apply to the Schengen area as a whole, it does not matter whether you are in France or Italy, you can only stay five days.

Comment: @AlexPunzalan note also that 5 days does not mean 120 hours: You must leave by 23:59:59 on the fifth day.

Comment: @phoog I edited that into the answer, it's too important not to.